# Powershell Startup Script to Delete Folders in all User Profiles Not working

Tags: powershell

I have a script that will uninstall Google Backup and Sync. However, this script leaves the Google Drive folder for each users profile on the machine. After some research to delete the folders I tried using following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\*\Google Drive" | Foreach-Object {Remove-Item $_ -Recurse -Force}
```

This works as expected when I run the script while logged into the machine, but it doesn't work when I put the script into a startup GPO.  Any suggestions how I can delete the folders and contents for all user profiles during startup?

Comment: Add the task to `Task Scheduler` and give the privilege `Run with highest privileges` and `Run whether the user is logged on or not`. That's one way of doing it.

Comment: Aren't installed program shortcuts located at `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`?

Comment: The shortcut for the user's Google Drive folder is located in the users Desktop Folder.  I am able to delete this by using 'Remove-Item -Path 'C:\Users\*\Desktop\Google Drive.lnk' -Force -Recurse' but i'm not able to delete the users Google Drive folder which is located in their profile.

Comment: @INotKnowScripting `-Recurse` is unnecessary when you're deleting a single file.  `-Path` accepts wildcards as you're already using one.  The `-Recurse` flag on `Remove-Item` is bugged and continues to be as part of its implementation.  You can clean up your example by trying the following: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\*\Google Drive' -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Force`